# How to do a HTTP POST Request that requires authentication using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I have a simple webserver that requires authentication to perform actions. Now I would like to trigger a single action (pressing a button): `my-action` through a javaScript, `myscript.js`, using node.js from command line. I have made this script:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var uurl = 'http://builder.internal:8012/binders/job-a/history/132/my-action'
request.get(uurl).auth('myuser', 'mypass', false);
var r = request.post(uurl, function optionalCallback (err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
})
var form = r.form()

// Runt the action
form.append('submit', 'my-action')
```

From ubuntu I run this script using node.js but I get:

```
$ node myscript.js 
Upload successful!  Server responded with: see <a href='../../../../authzfail'>../../../../authzfail</a>
```

I know its far fetched that this should work but maybe someone can give me a few pointers to what I need to look into?

Comment: Have you looked at passport.js?  http://passportjs.org/

Comment: yes I have looked at it and am trying to setup an example. But meanwhile it could be nice to know how to do it using request.